# hyphenate-character in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Can anybody advice me how I can to force to work css style hyphenate-character in google-chrome? I write -webkit-hyphenate-character, but it isn't work(

thanks!

Comment: And what, specifically, did you write in CSS? I believe you should have something like: `elementSelector {hyphenate-character: "\2112";}`

Comment: David Thomas, yes, I wrote this. And it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you show the relevant code in a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo? So we can see what's going on, and we can experiment more easily.

Comment: Looks like it's not implemented yet: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47083

Comment: David Thomas, this is my bit of code: http://jsfiddle.net/JhC6P/. Suppose it has small width, and words are broken, but the hyphenate-character between parts of words isn't inserted.

Comment: jfrej, it'll be fun if it's true...

Answer (score 2):

Chrome supports `-webkit-hyphenate-character`, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYLKq/).

But it does not seem to support automatic hyphenation yet. This is why my jsfiddle demo uses [Hyphenator.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/), which processes the text content, performing hyphenation and adding soft hyphens. You could alternatively hyphenate manually, adding soft hyphens, e.g. using the `&shy;` entity.

Note that for Hyphenator.js as well as for automatic hyphenation in browsers that support it, the `lang` attribute is needed to specify the language of the contet.

Comment: Yes, yours JS-library work very fine - I tried it :) But my client decided to use light solution - CSS :(